# Mysql: how to save a timestamp UTC without it being altered from mysql timezone?

Tags: mysql, laravel, unix-timestamp

This question is different from problem to store timestamp into datetime. 
I have a timestamp, and so no tz info.
Also I cannot alter my db structure 
I am using eloquent, but it worth to say that this problem happens also doing manually a MySQL query insert

### What I am doing

My API received this timestamp:

```
1572864543
```

It's

```
Assuming that this timestamp is in seconds:
GMT: Monday 4 November 2019 10:49:03
Your time zone: lunedì 4 novembre 2019 11:49:03 GMT+01:00
```

When I save on the db, I have NO idea of what is the user's MySQL timezone configuration, but I need that MySQL absolutely do not alters my timestamp.

What I'm sure is that MySQL column is a `timestamp`

I know that storing a timestamp in Laravel requires a conversion in a sql-like string

I tried to used

```
Carbon::createFromTimestamp($claims["date"])->toDateTimeString();
```

### Problem

It works, but MySQL gets my string, applies *its* timezone setting, shit to UTC and the save internally the new timestamp.

So when retrieving

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(received_ts)
```

I got the wrong result.

### Question

I absolutely need to keep my timestamp UNALTERED into the db. How can I save a timestamp without altering it?

### Mixed infos

The reason of this is that my product is installed in an unpredictable server timezone; I also cannot force the user to change db timezone to UTC.

Actually my app's timezone is already forced to 'UTC' via laravel `config/app.php` file

```
'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Comment: are you using eloquent ?

Comment: Can you change the column type? In that case changing it from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME would solve the problem. Per the doc: `MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)`

Comment: Why not store the timestamp as an integer then? Surely MySQL or your application won't change a raw numeric value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved forcing utc in the options of my MySQL connection configuration.

MySQL now do not alters any timestamps